# ffmpeg failed with webm

Tags: ffmpeg, webm

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg '-y' '-i' '/Users/l/htdocs/5a4def2049313.webm' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'libfaac' '-b:v' '415k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-vf'  '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/var/tmp//ffmpeg-passes5a4def443e5eaepy3b/pass-5a4def443e6a2' '/Users/l/htdocs/5a4def2049313.mp4'
```

This command comes out with error like:

```
ratecontrol_init: can't open stats file
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height';
```

This command is generated by a library. This library works fine with other formats and is also ok with fewer parameters like:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg '-y' '-i' '/Users/l/htdocs/5a4def2049313.webm'  '/Users/l/htdocs/5a4def2049313.mp4'
```

Error occurs only when dealing with webm. What is the problem with the first command?

Answer (score 0):

## The problems

- You used the `-vf` option (video filter) but without declaring any filters. This option requires a filter name. Either add a filter or remove `-vf`.
- Your `-passlogfile` path is non-existent. Check that `/var/tmp//ffmpeg-passes5a4def443e5eaepy3b/` exists before attempting to write to it. Also note the `//` typo.
- Why are you not using the [x264 encoding presets](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#a2.Chooseapresetandtune)? They were designed so you don't have to incorrectly use a billion options.
- Any particular reason you are apparently using two-passes? You should [use a single pass using `-crf`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#crf) instead of `-b:v` unless you need a specific output file size.
- [`libfaac` is old and has been removed from FFmpeg some time ago](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=dc0f711459e0c682bf9f94ba38d26736e90cff45). If you're using it your `ffmpeg` is old and outdated. [Upgrade](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and use `aac` instead.

## Fixed example

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg '-y' '-i' '/Users/l/htdocs/5a4def2049313.webm' '-c:v' 'libx264' '-preset' 'slow' '-c:a' 'aac' '-b:a' '128k' '-movflags' '+faststart' '/Users/l/htdocs/5a4def2049313.mp4'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use your suggestion, another problem occurs.  

`ffmpeg -i /path/to/input.mp4 -preset fast -crf 1 /path/to/output.mp4`.  i use this command on two files,  one 17M file reduce size to 8m, another 86M file raise size to 128M. The size of output file become unpredictable.    

My project need to control the size of output file, not very specifically, but regularly.
I used to do this by set the bit rate option , but crf seems like a nicer option. 

How can i control the size more regularly?

Comment: @Allen_Tsang A CRF value of 1 should never be used. As stated in the link I provided, try a value between ~17-28 where 17 is visually lossless or nearly so and 28 is a lower quality but smaller file size. Use the highest value that still provides an acceptable quality then use that value for everything. Use the slowest preset you have patience for.